# Robolectric, inflating layout with reference to a float type in dimens.xml throws NumberFormatException: For input string: "@0"

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-testing

Roblectric throws an Excpetion when trying to inflate res/layout/some_layout.xml with the following snippet of xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/some_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="@dimen/some_value" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

This is the value in dimens.xml

```
  <item name="some_value" format="float" type="dimen">0</item>
```

but I get the following error when trying to inflate res/layout/some_layout.xml

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@0"
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:422)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.$$robo$$TypedArray_42b1_getFloat(TypedArray.java:287)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.$$robo$$LayoutParams_5d9a___constructor__(LinearLayout.java:1813)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1809)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.$$robo$$LinearLayout_e83a_generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1721)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$LayoutInflater_1d1f_rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
```

Some important info:

1) This error is gone if I replace "@dimen/some_margin" in some_layout.xml with "0" (no quotes on either).

2) The app successfully inflates the layout on an emulator and real device.

3) I am able to inflate other layouts with Robolectric (but they don't use a float type in dimens.xml).

4) For my purposes, the dimens must be of type float.

I'm thinking the problem has something to do with some_value in dimens.xml being a float type.

Can anyone shed some insight as to why this Exception is thrown?  A solution to inflate this layout using a float type dimens.xml value would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build? Sometimes the compiled xml files aren't updated properly on incremental builds, which can cause weird errors.

Comment: check this https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/issues/30

Comment: thanks guys for the help.  I've done some further investigation on this issue, and have updated the problem.